# SQLite real all string rows

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm trying to get all `string` type rows with specified `id` from a table.

I keep getting the error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`.
I tried `try {} catch {}` to see if there was a more detailed exception, which there wasn't.

This is what I've got.

```
var ReadReasons = _db.CreateCommand();
ReadReasons.CommandText = $"SELECT reason FROM Warns WHERE id = '{user}' AND guildId = '{guild}'";
SqliteDataReader ReadReasonData = await ReadReasons.ExecuteReaderAsync();
if (ReadReasonData.HasRows)
{
    while (ReadReasonData.Read())
    {
        foreach (var reas in ReadReasonData)
        {
            ReadWarnReason.Add((string)reas);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: double check that you have initialize your _db

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception? Additionally, you should be aware that this way of populating a query is generally vulnerable to SQL Injection Attacks. I don't know if Sqlite supports parameterized queries, but if it does, I'd *strongly* advise using them.

Comment: It doesn't _exactly_ say which line is throwing the exception. I'd love if it did.
I have initialized my `_db` at the top of the document, and I have a few methods which use it from there and they work fine.

Comment: Could it be that this is throwing an error?
`public List<string> ReadWarnReason { get; set; }
while (ReadReasonData.Read())
                {
                    foreach (var reas in ReadReasonData)
                    {
                        ReadWarnReason.Add((string)reas);
                    }
                }`
_Very ugly format, but It's readable I guess?_